# Undefined res in API requests in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need a little help with Next JS API responses. I have coded an fetch request in `api/proxy/page.js`

```js
export default (req, res ) => {

        fetch('https://www.example.com')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            resolve(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
            reject(error);
        });

    
        res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

And I am accessing it from a testendpoint from the client side:

```js
const apiUrl = `/api/proxy`;
const res = await fetch(apiUrl,
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
 });
```

but when I do so, I am getting this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
    at eval (./app/api/proxy/page.js:22:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (./app/api/proxy/page.js:11:12)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
  21 |
  22 |
> 23 |         res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
```

Basically res is undefined. Am I doing something wrong?

I've tried to return directly using 'return', which returns a non-json response.

Comment: is this nextjs 13?

Comment: Yep, it is Nextjs 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your route is set up wrong and needs a few changes.

Firstly change the name of the file from

```
api/proxy/page.js
```

to

```
api/proxy/route.js
```

NextJS 13 has specific functions to handle the requests as yours is a get the top of your file should be.

```
export async function GET(request) {...
```

Then you need to adjust how the response is sent

```
res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
```

should be

```
return NextResponse.json({ name:'John Doe' }, {status: 200})
```

and don't forget to import

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
```